# Bumblebee2 output left/right images corrupted

Tags: ros, camera1394, stereo, bumblebee2, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04
Ros: fuerte
Pkg: camera1394, bumblebee2 (partial code) migration to fuerte

Fotmat bumblebee2: format7_mode3 (1024x768)

It seems the 2 outputs images publish well but:

As mentioned [here:](http://answers.ros.org/question/40690/bumblebee1394-corrupted-output-data/)

My left and right images are corrupted. It seems the output array have hollows (no information) and I see void points in the images.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55506/bumblebee2-output-left/right-images-corrupted/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try using the [camera1394stereo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394stereo) driver.  It is basically the camera1394 driver adopted for stereo cameras. We have been using it for our bumblebee2 cameras for a while now. We stream the images in raw bayer format from the cameras to not saturate the firewire bus too much and let image_proc do the color conversion and rectification.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
I did not know about this driver. Thanks for posting. I'll mention it on http://ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2013-02-21**:
Thanks but I used it and get the same corrupted outputs as my program.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-02-21**:
Then I would try the original pointgrey software to check your camera. We use this driver for four bumblebee2 cameras and it works fine. Maybe your cam is broken?

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2013-02-21**:
Ok I use the pointgrey software (triclops and pnmutils) and works very good. I try put triclops and ROS together but I have a problem with boost libraries. Maybe the problem is the way I launch the pkg. Would you give me more information like the steps you do to launch the nodes? Thanks

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-02-21**:
We launch the camera1394stereo_node with this parameter file: http://pastebin.com/1ugc1Zzt You can use dynamic_reconfigure to change some parameters online and try different settings.

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-02-21**:
We launch the camera1394stereo_node with this parameter file: http://pastebin.com/1ugc1Zzt

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2013-02-26**:
Thanks a lot. I'll try as soon as I get the camera again.

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-04-02**:
Hi Stephane, I just want to know if you had a good disparity image result with your bumblebee2. I am using it to extract pointClouds and the result is not really good because of the bad calibration results. How can i use the calibration files of point grey with ROS ? Is it possible ?

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-04-02**:
Or to publish the rectified images directly threw ROS ...

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-04-02**:
@INSA please ask a new question so that more people are able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With no access to this device, there is really no way for us to support it directly as part of camera1394. I wish there were some way, as the differences are relatively small.

All I can suggest is that Format 7 modes often behave strangely on many different 1394 cameras. You might experiment with the more standard modes or with using different Format 7 modes.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1